# Setting elapsed time and changing the decimals in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, benchmarking

As you might know that there is a function in benchmark property called elapsed_time(). The parameters are as follow:

```
elapsed_time([$point1 = ''[, $point2 = ''[, $decimals = 4]]])
```

I'm trying to set value to 3rd parameter with value 2. Here's my simple code:

```
echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('', '', 2);
```

But it still returns as default with four digits decimal behind the dot.

Can you tell me why it don't work? Thank you so much for you help! I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set benchmarks, then it works. In your example there is no start-point and no end-point, hence the third parameter is ignored.

so the correct usage would be:

```
<?php $this->benchmark->mark('startpoint');?>
    //your code
<?php $this->benchmark->mark('endpoint');?>
<?php echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('startpoint', 'endpoint', 2);?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I didn't know if the first or second parameter is NULL, then the rest will be ignored.